# Linq percentage in C# MVC

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am using MVC3 with c# and I'm trying to get the percentage from the following in my model:

I retrieve the numbers:

```
 ... Code omitted
 AgeGroup = g.Key.AgeGroup,
 Count = (int)g.Count(),
Total = (int)
(from vw_masterview0 in ctx.vw_MasterViews
select new
{
vw_masterview0.ClientID
}).Count() 
... Code omitted
```

I need to divide:

percent = Count/Total * 100

I have no idea how to format this in Linq.

Answer (score 6):

You first need to cast to `decimal` or `double` to avoid integer division. After multiplying with 100 and rounding, you need to cast back to `int`.

The casts of the `Count()`s to `int` on the other hand are useless, `Count()` already returns an integer.

```
int count = g.Count();
int total = ctx.vw_MasterViews.Count();
int percent = (int)Math.Round((Decimal)count/(Decimal)total*100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Comment: Thanks, now I get this error: For translation to SQL, the Math.Round method needs a MidpointRounding parameter. Use 'AwayFromZero' to specify the SQL function ROUND.

Comment: Then do what it says. I've updated my answer to include a rounding mode. I suspect this happens because SQL doesn't support banker's round, which is the default rounding.